# Emacs calendar: how to reset column alignment

Tags: org-mode, calendar, align

On my Agenda view (C-u C-c .) I have a "strange" effect. Line and column are not aligned:

[image]

How can I reset it?

Comment: That's not an agenda: that's the calendar. I suspect you are using a variable-width font. I would recommend that you choose a fixed-width font for everything to begin with: proportional fonts are a PITA for tabular data in general. Click on the `Options` menu button, click on `Set Default Font...` and choose a font with `mono` in its name (I use `Liberation Mono Regular`). Once you know a bit more about emacs, you can change to a proportional font for *some* buffers, but for now I recommend you stick with a fixed-width (aka `monospace`) font.

Answer (score 0):

As NickD told, I've choose the first mono font (Andale mono 16 pt) and all works well.

Thank you

Renato